# is it possible to omit the form tag in html

Tags: html, forms

```
<form name="searchform" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8" action="index.html">
        <input type="search" name="searchbar" placeholder="Search for your favorite song ..." autocomplete="on" autofocus><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submitsearch" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Can the form element be omitted

Answer (score 0):

The `<form>` element can be omitted, but then the only way to use the contents of the `<input>` is with JavaScript.